# strpos is not defined in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using the functions strpos(string, string) in javascript. In Firefox, Opera and IE the page loads fine, but in Chrome I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: strpos is not defined. The page I am working on is http://seniorproject.korykirk.com/0xpi2.php

Comment: I'm lost! are you talking about the PHP function strpos() or one of the JavaScript functions substr() or substring()?

Answer (score 13):

Use [`haystack.indexOf(needle)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp).

Answer (score 8):

*strpos* is not part of the [ECMAScript Language Specification ECMA-262 3rd edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (commonly known as javascript)

Like Artelius wrote, use
[haystack.indexOf(needle,start)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp) or [haystack.lastIndexOf(needle,start)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastIndexOf.asp) (where *start* is optional)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP functions in javascript, use php.js

Here's `strpos()` http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos:545